# Create composed unique key field with trigger after insert in SQLITE

Tags: sqlite, triggers, key, case, unique

I have a table with multiple columns and one (unique key) should be a value composed from the values of other two columns.

```
CREATE TABLE batches (
    id   TEXT PRIMARY KEY UNIQUE,
    name TEXT NOT NULL,
    project_id INTEGER);
```

On each insert, I want to generate the id based on the value of 'name' and 'project_id' (this one can be null):

```
INSERT INTO batches (name,project_id) VALUES
     ('21.01',NULL),
     ('21.01',1),
     ('21.02',2);
```

So, I have created a table TRIGGER but doesn't execute.

```
CREATE TRIGGER create_batches_id 
AFTER INSERT ON batches FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
    UPDATE batches 
    SET id = SELECT quote(name ||"_"|| (CASE project_id 
            WHEN NULL THEN '' ELSE project_id END )
        FROM batches WHERE rowid = (SELECT MAX(rowid) FROM batches))
    WHERE rowid = (SELECT MAX(rowid) FROM batches);
END;
```

Error:

> SQL Error [1]: [SQLITE_ERROR] SQL error or missing database (near "SELECT": syntax error)

I expect:

```
id = 21.01_
id = 21.01_1
id = 21.01_2
```

What am I doing wrong? If I run only the SELECT/CASE statment it returns ok: '21.01_2'

I have also tried without the quote() function, no success.

**UPDATE I:**

I have managed to execute the whole create trigger statement (parenthesis were missing):

```
CREATE TRIGGER create_batch_id 
AFTER INSERT ON batches FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
    UPDATE batches 
    SET id = (SELECT name ||"_"|| (CASE project_id WHEN NULL THEN 0 ELSE project_id END ) FROM batches WHERE rowid = (SELECT MAX(rowid) FROM batches) )
    WHERE rowid = (SELECT MAX(rowid) FROM batches);
END;
```

It seems my editor (DBeaver) has a glitch with the following new line character. If it is inside the selection it runs into this exception (or I am missing something):

> SQL Error [1]: [SQLITE_ERROR] SQL error or missing database (incomplete input)

If I manually select only the above lines (from CREATE to ;), the trigger is created, however, not the expected result. If value in project_id is NULL, no id value is created.

Comment: I have also tried to concatenate the quotes:
id = SELECT '''' || name ||"_"|| (CASE project_id 
   WHEN NULL THEN '' ELSE project_id END ) || ''''
  FROM batches WHERE rowid = (SELECT MAX(rowid) FROM batches)
with no success either.

Comment: Why do you want to do this? You can define a UNIQUE constraint on the combination of the 2 columns.

Comment: this database will have no visual app to handle it. I will manage it only by command line or db client, and I thought it will be faster for me to identify the 'batch' I am working on in multiple views, without loading all it's details, just by viewing the unique id. Oh, and also by curiosity and the appetite for learning, too

Comment: Check my answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't add the column `id` in the table.
Instead define the combination of `name` and `project_id` as the `PRIMARY KEY` of the table, so that it is also `UNIQUE`:

```
CREATE TABLE batches (
    name TEXT NOT NULL,
    project_id INTEGER,
    PRIMARY KEY(name, project_id)
)
```

Then, whenever you need that `id` you can run a query:

```
SELECT name || '_' || COALESCE(project_id, '') AS id, 
       name, 
       project_id
FROM batches
```

Or create a view:

```
CREATE VIEW v_batches AS
SELECT name || '_' || COALESCE(project_id, '') AS id, 
       name, 
       project_id
FROM batches
```

and query the view:

```
SELECT * FROM v_batches
```

See the [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlite_3.27&fiddle=f18aab185e1fd526787b877d1ebddcc0).

Or if your version of SQLite is 3.31.0+ you can have the column `id` as a [generated column](https://sqlite.org/gencol.html):

```
CREATE TABLE batches (
    name TEXT NOT NULL,
    project_id INTEGER,
    id TEXT GENERATED ALWAYS AS (name || '_' || COALESCE(project_id, '')),
    PRIMARY KEY(name, project_id)
);
```